# Как подключить сервер к Microsoft SQL Managment Studio?

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, есть файл.sql [resources.oreilly.com](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9780596007270/blob/master/LearningSQLExample.sql). Файл расчитан на MySQL версии 4 и выше. У меня установлена Microsoft SQL Managment Studio. Хотелось бы там открыть этот файл. Открыв, выдает очень много ошибок в синтаксисе файла. Что нужно сделать?
Нашел вот одну тему это оно? [wiki.oktell.ru](http://wiki.oktell.ru/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_MySQL)

Comment: 1. У вас вопрос не вяжется с его содержимым; 2. Если очень хочется открыть MySql код в MS студии - его придется предварительно  сконвертировать; 3. А лучше возьмите для этого родной инструмент  https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ или этот https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек.

Comment: Прошу прощенья за вопрос. Хотел попрактиковаться на T-SQL, но думаю MySQL тоже пригодится. Скачал Navicat.